# Listview - AfterLabelEdit event is called again and is causing issues with my code. c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, listview, label

after trying to find a solution, I can't see any way to get my code work whit all I need, due is causing an exception, I found what's the issue, but I don't know how can I solve it if that is what I need.

I'm using ListView and AfterLabelEdit event, when the user is editing the label, after edit the event is called, then inside of the AfterLabelEdit I'm editing again if an Item of the ListView is existing with the item text that the user entered.

Issue that I'm having is:

lvInterfaces_AfterLableEdit is called 2 times if the name match with an item in the listview this is causing that "e.label" is empty and this is not working with the condition (e.Label == lvInterfaces.Items[ItemIndex].Text)

any idea how to solve this?

this is my code:

```
    private void lvInterfaces_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
    {          
       for (int ItemIndex = 0; ItemIndex < lvInterfaces.Items.Count - 1; ItemIndex++)
       {
           if (e.Label == lvInterfaces.Items[ItemIndex].Text)
           {                   
               MessageBox.Show("Interface already exist, please select another name.", "Interface Duplicated", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
               lvInterfaces.Items[lvInterfaces.Items.Count - 1].BeginEdit();                   
               return;
           }
       }

       if (cAction == 'R')
           file.XmlInterfaceRename(e.Label, sOldInterfaceName);
       else if (cAction == 'N')
           file.XmlNewInterface(e.Label);
       else if (cAction == 'C')
           file.CopyInterface(e.Label, InterfaceSelected);            
    }
```

Comment: maybe setting the e.CancelEdit para before (?) calling BeginEdit again ?

Comment: @TaW what is happening is if the e.label = lvInterfaces.Items[ItemIndex].text match then it will use this line:
lvInterfaces.Items[lvInterfaces.Items.Count - 1].BeginEdit();
So this line called again lvInterfaces_AfterLabelEdit

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved!

Was very easy than I expected :/

just add e.label == null

if (e.Label == lvInterfaces.Items[ItemIndex].Text || e.Label == null)